# Inserting custom data attributes into jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, custom-data-attribute

Problem:

- I am using JQuery DataTables v1.10 for a work-related project.
- The project requires a Datatable to be defined and created with parsed JSON data passed in as the values of the table
- Once the datatable has been created, every cell in each column should have a click event that opens a pop in and pass in a list of names in JSON, received from an endpoint. The endpoint changes depending on which table cell is clicked.
- I think, upon datatable instantiation, I need to store some sort of unique information in an HTML5 data-attribute defined on each table cell element. I was hoping to declare a custom data-attribute (ex: data-endpoint = "endpoint id") but I'm not Sure if that is possible to do if the table rows are being dynamically generated via DataTables.

Because I don't know/understand what my options are, I'd like to describe what I ideally would like to do:

- Instantiate a datatable and pass it the parsed JSON data.
- On table instantiation, set a custom data-attribute on each table cell element.
- Access the table cell click event, pass it the information stored in the correct data-attribute, in order to get the correct endpoint.
- Create a popin that will display the results received from the endpoint.

The part I don't understand is how to create a custom data-attribute on the table cell element. Is this possible or do I need to think of another approach?

Answer (score 19):

You can try with the `createdRow` callback on instantiation. Example:

```
$table.dataTable({

    "destroy": true, // To replace existing data
    "data": jsonData,
    "columns": columns,

    // Per-row function to iterate cells
    "createdRow": function (row, data, rowIndex) {
        // Per-cell function to do whatever needed with cells
        $.each($('td', row), function (colIndex) {
            // For example, adding data-* attributes to the cell
            $(this).attr('data-foo', "bar");
        });
    }
});
```

I think this can help you to do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do something kind of like that.  I'm not sure about the rest, but I used the columnDefs option to set the attributes.

```
....
"destroy": true, // To replace existing data
"data": jsonData,
"columns": columns,
// Sets the attribute
"columnDefs": [{
    "targets":'_all',
    "createdCell": function(td){
        td.setAttribute('foo','bar');
    }
}]
...
```

It still uses the createdCell option, but it mimics what I found in their documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell).